# Использование forwarding (универсальных) ссылок в обычных функциях

Tags: c++, c++11, шаблоны-с++, rvalue

Я рассматриваю вариант внедрения в программу forwarding-ссылок в обычных функциях.

Например, раньше было написано так:

```
void f(const std::string & s)
{
    // используем s
}
```

Теперь же рассматривается такая альтернатива:

```
template < typename S, typename Enable = 
    std::enable_if_t < std::is_convertible_v < S, std::string > > >
void f(S && s)
{
     // используем s (не обязательно в std::forward, а как угодно)
}
```

Так предлагается сделать для функций, аргументы у которых не фундаментальных типов.

Зачем? - для получения потенциальной оптимизации за счет использования семантики перемещения, если пользователь соизволит подготовить и передать rvalue-объект.

Вопрос? - что может останавливать меня от массового внедрения такой концепции в коде?

Примечание к ответу: задумывался о разделении кода на заголовочные и исходные файлы (если речь идет о функции-члене класса), о возможных трудностях с перегрузками шаблона, об увеличении объема кода. С этими проблемами готов мириться.

Comment: вопрос на целую статью

Comment: @ARHovsepyan проблема в том, что основная масса статей посвящена разжевыванию того, что такое move-семантика, прямая передача и т.п. Я прекрасно осведомлен о том, что это и как работает. Мой вопрос в том, почему этот механизм можно или не стоит использовать так, как я описал.

Comment: Если вообще существуют какие-то веские причины так не поступать...

Comment: Не надо плодить монстров

Comment: @avp, только хотел написать то же самое...

Comment: @Jens, я ваш вопрос прекрасно понел, но  думаю тут простым ответом не отделаешься, хотя не отрицаю, что кто то может дать хороший исчерпающий ответ. P.S. typename Enable =  можно заменить на class =, поскольку это имя типа не используется

Comment: @ARHovsepyan Про Enable я знаю, просто особенности почерка. Насчет монстров даже не знаю, есть такое в C++ и от этого никуда не деться. А уж если требуется хорошая производительность - без монстров не обойтись. В той же стандартной библиотеке - взгляните на stdt::pair - что может быть проще и до какого монстра это дело разрослось. Я-то еще по божески предлагаю)

Comment: Перегрузка точно не проще?...

Comment: @Harry Это уже проходили - экспоненциальный рост количества перегрузок при увеличении количества аргументов функции. Поэтому, думаю не пойдет. Если имелась ввиду перегрузка под прием rvalue и lvalue.

Comment: Тогда что вас вообще смущает?

Comment: @Harry чувство сомнения с непривычки)

Comment: Я писал [статью](http://scrutator.me/post/2018/07/30/value_vs_reference.aspx) по смежной теме. Она как раз посвящена теме смены того, как передаются аргументы в современном C++, там же есть ссылки на книги и статьи людей, с разными мнениями. На мой взгляд, вариант кода из вопроса имеет смысл только тогда, когда его смысл _доказан_. Т.е. есть объективные данные, что это приносит ощутимые дивиденды. Я бы не принял подобный код на code review как код по умолчанию, потому что несколько тактов в _некоторых_ случаях не стоят ухудшения читабельности.

Comment: Также рекомендую [видео](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PNRju6_yn3o) Юсуттиса (если не ошибаюсь, то в этом видео как раз хороша раскрыта тема). Да и другие его видео с CppCon стоит посмотреть. Я уже всего не помню, но он этой теме не мало посвятил времени.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1148546/398802