# Лучший способ добавления элемента в вектор строк

Tags: c++, строки, vector, c++17

В чём разница между следующими способами вставки строки в вектор строк, хранящийся в некотором классе? Что лучше использовать? Может быть есть другой вариант?

```
void add_string(std::string str) {
    strings.push_back(std::move(str));
}

void add_string(std::string str) {
    strings.emplace_back(std::move(str));
}

void add_string(const std::string& str) {
    strings.push_back(str);
}

void add_string(std::string_view str) {
    strings.emplace_back(str.data());
}
```

Уточню: меня интересует, что лучше использовать с точки зрения современных практик написания кода на C++, а не в какие ассемблерные инструкции это может выйти на одном компиляторе, в какие на другом. Разница в миллисекунды неважна, разница в вызове 2 копирующих конструкторов против 1 важна, другими словами.

Comment: А почему не `void add_string(const std::string& str) {
    strings.emplace_back(str);
}`?

Comment: @Harry для этого случая тоже интересно узнать, в чём отличие от 3 варианта

Comment: первый(второй то же самое, что и первый) и четвертый варианты есть полная ерунда. Остается третий.

Comment: @ARHovsepyan объясните, почему так.

Comment: Пока что 4 варианта ответа - и все разные. Кому верить? :)

Comment: push_back вызывает  emplace_back(std::move(str)). Так что первый и второй способ одинаковы. Но функция сначала копирует объект, потом перемещает в элемент вектора. Смысл какой? .. Четвертый вариант просто просматривает вашу строку с помощью другого объекта и передает его информацию в вектор, . Зачем, если функция не выполняет что то еще?.. Другое дело, если вы сразу переместите строку в конец вектора, передавая  универсальную ссылку. Цель использования std::string_view , в основном является просмотром строки, о чем говорит и название типа.

Comment: Передавая четвертым способом, вы просто задействуете посредника, чтобы передавать его информацию об объекте, хотя могли просто передать этот же объект или, если не нужно хранить его содержимое,, перемещать, передавая как std::string&&(универсальная ссылка)

Comment: std::string&& - это не универсальная ссылка. rvalue ссылка.

Comment: @ARHovsepyan "push_back вызывает emplace_back(std::move(str))" - это почему? Можете сослаться на документацию или что-нибудь подтверждающее это?

Comment: Нет, я не на экзамене у вас. Смотрите сами

Comment: @ARHovsepyan так что смотреть?

Comment: на реализацию std::vector<std::string>::push_back (Ctrl + click\

Comment: Это некорректный вопрос, так как предложенные варианты не являются альтернативами. То бишь это не разные варианты одного действия, а разные действия. Первые два еще можно сравнивать , но остальные - нет.

Comment: @user7860670 мне интересны ситуации, в которых надо использовать эти варианты. Я не утверждал, что они эквивалентны.

Comment: @ueber А я нигде не писал, что вы утверждали, что они эквивалентны... Я написал что они не являются альтернативами. Соответственно из них нельзя выбрать лучший.

Answer (score 3):

Во-первых, как уже написали в соседних ответах, из-за SSO для коротких строк копирующий конструктор `std::string` может работать быстрее перемещающего.

Но если вы не решили удариться в микрооптимизацию, я бы "по умолчанию" считал, что лучше переместить, чем копировать.

---

1. ```
   void add_string(std::string str) {
       strings.push_back(std::move(str));
   }
   ```
2. ```
   void add_string(std::string str) {
       strings.emplace_back(std::move(str));
   }
   ```
3. ```
   void add_string(const std::string& str) {
      strings.push_back(str);
   }
   ```
4. ```
   void add_string(std::string_view str) {
       strings.emplace_back(str.data());
   }
   ```

Между (1) и (2) не должно быть вообще никакой разницы. Оба вызывают перемещающий конструктор, плюс конструктор для параметра (копирующий, перемещающий, или еще какой-то).
Субъективно (1) мне нравится больше.

(3) вызывает копирующий конструктор. Плюс, в некоторых случаях, конструктор для временной строки (например если передать в параметр строковой литерал).

(4) тоже копирует строку, но временный объект не создает. Но он лишний раз пересчитывает длину строки (как уже сказал KoVadim; правильно: `emplace_back(str.data(), str.size())`). Если это исправить, то (4) лучше, чем (3), потому что тут никогда не будет создаваться временный объект.

Еще вариант: использовать (3), но добавить перегрузку с параметром `std::string &&str` и `emplace_back(std::move(str))`. Этот вариант явно лучше, чем (3). И лучше, чем (1), потому что всегда делает на 1 перемещение меньше.
Минус - если у функции больше одного параметра, то нужно 2<sup>N</sup> перегрузок.

Еще вариант: шаблон с forwarding-ссылкой в качестве параметра, и `emplace_back`.

---

**Вывод**

Упорядочил варианты <s>от хороших к плохим</s> по возрастанию числа вызовов разных конструкторов.

1. Шаблон с forwarding-ссылкой в качестве параметра.
   Из пушки по комарам.

   <sup>Вызывает один copy- или move- или еще какой-то конструктор.</sup>
2. (3) + перегрузка для rvalue
   Минус: нужно много кода (особенно если параметров больше одного, тогда будет 2<sup>N</sup> перегрузок).

   <sup>Вызывает один copy-конструктор, или один move-конструктор, или (если аргумент - не `std::string`, а например литерал) move-конструктор плюс еще какой-то конструктор.</sup>
3. (1), (2)
   Хороший вариант, компромисс между скоростью и объемом кода.
   Стилистически (2) мне нравится меньше.

   <sup>Вызывает один move-конструктор, плюс один copy- или move- или еще какой-то конструктор.</sup>
4. (4) исправленный

   <sup>Копирует строку.</sup>
5. (3)

   <sup>Один копирующий конструктор. Если аргумент не `std::string`, то дополнительно еще какой-то конструктор.</sup>

Comment: я бы только уточнил "критерий хорошести". как по мне, то не только производительность, но и "разумность". И тут вариант 2 просто пасет задних.

Comment: @KoVadim Поменял формулировку немного. А чем он плох? Мне больше нравятся 2 вызова перемещающего конструктора, чем один копирующего.

Comment: emplace_back принимает параметры конструктора, а не сам объект для вставки. Теоретически, это может дать больше производительность. Да, у большинства классов есть "функция, которая принимает объект этого же класса как параметр" - копирующий конструктор. Поэтому второй вариант и работает. Но он немного через одно место. Я иногда на собеседованиях встречаю мнение, что emplace_back как раз делает мув, а push_back - нет (хотя мы знаем, что это не нет).

Comment: @KoVadim А, так вы про второй вариант из вопроса, а не второй пункт в моем списке? Тогда согласен, `emplace_back` там не к месту.

Comment: конечно о нем. о ком же ещё.

Comment: Теперь ждем минусатора, который ходит и всем минусует.

Answer (score 2):

Вам уже дали довольно полное объяснение для каждого упомянутого Вами способа вставки, но, на мой взгляд, некоторые моменты были объяснены не достаточно детально, а порой даже *неверно*.

По этой причине я хотел бы остановиться именно на первом способе:

```cpp
void add_string(std::string str)
{
    strings.push_back(std::move(str));
}
```

Предыдущими участниками были сделаны несколько заявлений, с которыми я в корне не согласен:

> - Ох, очередная попытка вставить move, что бы оптимизировать
> - Итого, первые два варианта неверно используют move семантику
> - В первом случае строка копируется два раза

Итак, давайте разберемся, что же здесь происходит. Строка передается в функцию по значению, затем используется `std::move` для приведения типа последней к rvalue-ссылке, что заставляет компилятор выбрать *правильную* перегрузку `push_back`, а именно - ту, которая принимает значение, тип которого является rvalue-ссылкой.

Смотрите, `push_back` перегружен следующим образом:

```cpp
void push_back( const T& value ); // 1
void push_back( T&& value );      // 2
```

Тогда, после приведения типа `str` к rvalue-ссылке будет использован именно второй вариант член-функции `push_back` - т.е., при вставке будет вызван move-конструктор, но никак не copy-конструктор.

---

Далее, что касается передачи по значению: и здесь я не вижу никаких проблем. Давайте рассмотрим несколько примеров вызова данной функции:

```cpp
// 1
add_string("...");

// 2
std::string s { "..." }
add_string(std::move(s));

// 3
std::string s { "..." };
add_string(s);
```

Данные примеры иллюстрируют универсальность данного способа, а именно:

1. Переданное значение не обязательно должно быть типа `std::string` (в первом примере в качестве аргумента была передана C-строка).
2. Передача по значению не подразумевает обязательное использование copy-конструктора. В частности, во втором примере, не смотря на то, что наша функция все еще принимает аргумент по значению, copy-конструктор не вызывается. Как и в самом первом примере (с push_back), мы приводим тип `s` к rvalue-ссылке, и, таким образом, заставляем компилятор использовать именно move-конструктор.
3. Третий пример является иллюстрацией того, как следует использовать данную функцию, если нам все же необходима копия строки. Так как в данном случае мы не используем `std::move`, то в результате будет вызван copy-конструктор.

Как видите, данную функцию можно использовать как для перемещения строки, так и для ее копирования. Давайте подытожим (номер пункта однозначно соответствует номеру примера из вышеприведенного кода):

1. Вызов конструктора (копирование C-строки), вызов move-конструктора
2. Вызов move-конструктора (x2)
3. Вызов copy-конструктора, вызов move-конструктора

Теперь я предлагаю Вам рассмотреть теже самые примеры, только для функции, которая принимает lvaluе-ссылку:

```cpp
void add_string(const std::string& str)
{
    strings.push_back(str);
}

// 1
add_string("...");

// 2
std::string s { "..." }
add_string(s);

// 3
// Аналогичен 2
```

1. Вызов конструктора (копирование C-строки), вызов copy-конструктора
2. Вызов copy-конструктора

Я считаю, что к этому моменту я привел достаточное количество аргументов, чтобы Вы могли самостоятельно сделать выводы, стоит ли использовать первый вариант или же нет (если что, ответ *да, стоит*).

---

Немного про подводные камни. Не всегда использование move-семантики приводит к увеличению производительности. Более того, это даже не всегда приводит к ожидаемому нами поведению.

Пример 1.

```cpp
const std::string s { "..." };
add_string(std::move(s));
```

Несмотря на то, что мы использовали `std::move` чтобы привести тип к rvalue-ссылке, мы не добьемся нужного результата - объект будет скопирован. Все дело в том, что объект `s` изначально имел тип `const std::string`, и после приведения `const` сохранится - соответственно, вместо *ожидаемого* вызова move-конструктора мы получим вызов copy-конструктора.

Пример 2. 
Это SSO - [small string optimization](https://akrzemi1.wordpress.com/2014/04/14/common-optimizations/). Более детальную информацию Вы можете найти и без моей помощи, но, если позволите, я бы предложил Вам  узнать о данном виде оптимизации путем ознакомления с реализацией `std::string` в стандартной библиотеке.

Итак, каким образом SSO изменяет семантику перемещения объектов `std::string`: до определенного размера строка хранит свои данные на стеке, а именно, в специально отведенном для этого буфере, который имеет фиксированный размер. После того, как размер строки достигает определенного предела, для данных выделяется место на куче, данные из буфера копируются в новую выделенную область памяти и с этого момента мы работаем только с кучей. Что же произойдет, если мы попытаемся переместить строку, данные которой в данный момент хранятся в буфере? Она будет скопирована. Вы можете свапнуть указатели на данные в куче для двух строк, но Вы не может проделать тоже самое со "стековыми" данными. Пример ниже является иллюстрацией вышесказанному:

Пример:

```cpp
std::string s1 { "abc" };
std::string s2 = std::move(s1);
```

P.S. Если захотите проверить данный пример кода, не нужно для этого использовать вывод - смотрите в отладчике (в частности, обратите внимание на то, что произодет после непосредственно копирования данных).

---

Что касается вышеупомянутой книги Скота Майерса - я так же советую Вам ее прочесть. Возможно, я где-то ошибся в своих суждениях, но я уверен, что в данной книге Вы найдете подтверждение моим словам, а самое главное - более детальное объяснение того, как все это работает.

---

UPD0: спасибо @KoVadim за исправление. Как оказалось, если объект типа `std::string` был выделен динамически, то буфер хранится не на стеке, а в куче (невероятно, но факт).

Comment: я об этом всем везде и упоминал. Собственно, более структурированно попытались пересказать мой ответ. Но и ошибок наделали. Да, то что для строк sso делает move конструктор чуть дороже не все знают.  Но вот только в ответе написали немного не то. Не на стеке сохраняется буфер, а внутри объекта std::string. А ухудшение происходит из за того, что размер нужно сделать нулевым (по стандарту)

Comment: @KoVadim, я Вас услышал. Если Вы внимательно читали то, что я написал (хотя, разумеется, Вы не обязаны были этого делать), Вы должны были понять, что я пытался не пересказать Ваш ответ, а опровергнуть Ваше утверждение о том, что "первые два варианта неверно используют move семантику" (в данном случае, я касался именно первого).

Comment: @KoVadim, ухудшение, как Вы выразились происходит из-за того, что нам приходится копировать данные из одного места в другое, вместо того, чтобы просто свопнуть указатели.

Comment: Я был бы весьма признателен Harry и HolyBlackCat, если бы они нашли время прочесть мой ответ и дать конструктивные пояснения, в чем я не прав.

Comment: я внимательно читал. И я не говорил, что в первом варианте неверно используется move семантика. Более того, в конце моего ответа есть предложение, что первый вариант плюс вариант перегрузки с rvalue ссылкой будет самое оно по Маерсу. А вот со свопом указателей - вот тут все плохо. Почему то все это цитируют. Кроме "свопа указателей" нужно ещё и размер сповпнуть. Ваш ответ утверждает, что мой ответ неверный - это первый пункт и второе - не совсем правильно объясняет move при sso.

Comment: @KoVadim, да нет, говорили - `первые два варианта неверно используют move семантику`. В данном случае, мне интересен только первый вариант. И да, я не утверждал, что Ваш ответ неверный - я утверждал (и утверждаю), что не согласен только с тем, как Вы описали первый способ вставки.

Comment: @KoVadim, а какую именно ошибку я допустил, когда говорил о move/SSO?

Comment: Вы не читаете, что я пишу... ну почему... хотя начните просто с этого "до определенного размера строка хранит свои данные на стеке".

Comment: @KoVadim, нет, я настаиваю, укажите _конкретно_ на ошибку.

Comment: мне  третий раз написать?

Comment: @KoVadim, Вы еще первый раз не написали. Пока Вы только копируете текст, а я Вас прошу объяснить мне в чем ошибка.

Comment: Ваше утверждение ошибочно. строка (в случае sso) сохраняется внутри объекта std::string. А вот он может быть на стеке, а может и быть динамически выделен.

Comment: @KoVadim, в целом - я с Вами согласен, в частном - я говорил о конкретном примере, и в нем не было никаких аллокаций на куче. Но пусть даже так, я внесу изменения в ответ, спасибо за исправление. Теперь я прошу объяснить еще дав момента: почему Вы отказываетесь от своих слов (я не говорил, что в первом варианте неверно используется move семантика) - первый, второй - каких ошибок я "наделал" в объясении той части, которая не касается  SSO?

Comment: давайте я не буду начинать по новой объяснять все.

Comment: @KoVadim, кстати, Andrzej Krzemienski, тоже называет это _stack-allocated part_ - и на него никто не ругается. А этот человек уже несколько раз был докладчиком на CppCon. `давайте я не буду начинать по новой объяснять все` - хорошо. Только больше людей не обманывайте, пожалуйста.

Comment: если у нас именно передача параметра, то оно действительно сохраняется на стеке. Но это потому, что сам объект std::string там сохраняется. Но в общем случае - нет. (FYI:  я минус не ставил и даже не знаю, кто это здесь сделал всем)

Comment: *"Я был бы весьма признателен Harry и HolyBlackCat"* Меня призвали и я пришел... В целом с ответом согласен. Тоже не понял про *"первые два варианта неверно используют move семантику"*.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, спасибо!

Answer (score 2):

Самый лучший способ (упомянул его только 1 человек!):

```
template <typename T>
void add_string(T&& str) {
    strings.push_back(std::forward<T>(str));
}
```

Если вдруг нужны ещё перегрузки - дополнительно наложить концепт `std::same_as<std::string>`.

Почему?

1. Меньше всего вызовов конструкторов.
2. Не надо писать несколько перегрузок (для lvalue и rvalue), т.е. дублировать код.

Проверяем по коду автора:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>
#include <vector>


struct A {
    A() = default;

    A(const A&) {
        std::cout << "Copy\n";
    }

    A(A&&) noexcept {
        std::cout << "Move\n";
    }
};

struct B {
    B() {
        v.reserve(6);
    }

    template <typename T>
    void add_0(T&& a) {
        v.push_back(std::forward<T>(a));
    }

    void add_1(A a) {
        v.push_back(std::move(a));
    }

    void add_2(A a) {
        v.emplace_back(std::move(a));
    }

    void add_3(const A& a) {
        v.push_back(a);
    }

    void add_4(const A& a) {
        v.emplace_back(a);
    }

    std::vector<A> v;
};

int main() {
    B b{};
    A a{};

    b.add_0(a);
    std::cout << '\n';
    b.add_0(A{});
    std::cout << '\n';
    b.add_1(a);
    std::cout << '\n';
    b.add_2(a);
    std::cout << '\n';
    b.add_3(a);
    std::cout << '\n';
    b.add_4(a);
    std::cout << '\n';
}
```

Результат:

> Copy
>
> Move
>
> Copy Move
>
> Copy Move
>
> Copy
>
> Copy

Как видно, и для временного объекта, и для копии были вызваны по одному конструктору.

Comment: У Вас чудесный ответ. Только не забывайте, что изначально у нас была строка. И вполне может быть, что человек захочет добавить сишную строку. А эта тема не раскрыта в ответе. (но работать будет)

Answer (score 1):

Ох, очередная попытка вставить move, что бы оптимизировать. Более того, много людей до конца не понимают все это...

```
void add_string(std::string str) {
    strings.push_back(std::move(str));
}
```

будет вызван один конструктор копирования и один перемещения (минимум)

```
void add_string(std::string str) {
    strings.emplace_back(std::move(str));
}
```

Вариант извращения. Самый сложный вариант для понимания. emplace_back принимает параметры для конструктора. У string есть конструктор, который принимает string, так что конструктор копирования и размещающий new. Но emplace_back нужно уметь вызывать:)

```
void add_string(const std::string& str) {
    strings.push_back(str);
}
```

старый добрый понятный способ. Один конструктор копирования. Супер. Но может быть и два (если передается строка в виде си строки).

```
void add_string(std::string_view str) {
    strings.emplace_back(str.data());
}
```

вот это похоже на нормальный вызов emplace_back, но только конструктору строки придется позвать strlen (или аналог, что бы длину строки посчитать). Хотя оригинальная строка возможно его даже хранила. Так может его передать? И вот здесь emplace_back работает прямо как нужно.

```
void add_string(std::string_view str) {
    strings.emplace_back(str.data(), str.size());
}
```

теперь только нужно позвать конструктор. Другое дело, что здесь move семантика не работает - строку будут копировать.

Итого, первые два варианта неверно используют move семантику. третий способ хорош, четвертый, если исправить, также хорош, хоть и требует 17 плюсов. (специально для скептиков-минусаторов: это утверждение верно, если мы говорим об использовании **только одного из вариантов в целях оптимизации**.)

P.S. А как же move семантика, а как же скорость? В этом случае нужно иметь такую перегрузку

```
void add_string(std::string:&& str) {
    strings.push_back(std::move(str));
}

void add_string(const std::string& str) {
    strings.push_back(str);
}
```

P.S.S move семантика настолько проста, что ее почти никто не понимает:)

P.S.S.S если хочется по быстрому - используйте первый вариант, хотите оптимально - используйте свой третий плюс мой с && (да, использовать перегрузку). Детали - в книге Маерса в районе 166-170 страницы.

Comment: 1) Что такое "размещающий new"? 2) Почему "конструктору строки придется позвать strlen"?

Comment: 1 - [placement new](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/new) - такая форма new, которая не выделяет память, а использует переданную. 2. А потому что data - возвращает указатель на начало строки. А размера там нет. И его нужно будет узнать

Comment: Почему его надо узнать, если есть нулевой символ, показывающий конец строки?

Comment: @ueber - потому что этот ноль еще надо найти, а для этого надо перебрать всю строку до конца посимвольно.

Comment: Потому что копировать, наперед зная длину, мы можем по 16 байт за инструкцию (movdqa). А иначе увы, будем дергать по одному.

Comment: @gbg начинайте с этого https://lwn.net/Articles/416821/ и https://lwn.net/Articles/414467/ . Полностью всю историю где то читал отдельно.

Comment: Почему тогда говорят 1) оставить копирование на уровне параметров функции, т.е. делать передачу копии + move и 2) использовать std::string_view вместо const std::string& в параметрах? Неужели всё это бред и лучший вариант старый добрый из 98 стандарта?

Comment: нет, не бред. просто нужно смотреть на весь код, а не пытаться оптимизировать маленький кусочек.

Comment: @ueber, кстати, ко всему, что вам объясняли -- копировать, не зная заранее длину (для 0-терминируемых строк) не обязательно побайтно. Можно и пословно, [например, так](http://git.musl-libc.org/cgit/musl/tree/src/string/stpcpy.c) / (аналогично работает и strlen)

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/110205/discussion-on-answer-by-kovadim-------).

Comment: @ueber, потому что чтобы куда-то копировать, надо сначала кусок памяти, в который будет копирование, выделить. А чтобы его выделить, надо знать, сколько выделять. Ну и поводу strlen и побайтового прохода было [вот тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1040023/178988).

Comment: 1. В первом и втором случаях не обязательно вызывается конструктор копирования. Вместо этого там может быть второй вызов перемещающего конструктора (`add_string(move(...))`), либо вызов вообще другого конструктора (`add_string("...")`). 2. Не совсем понял, почему вы упоминаете placement-new в (2) но не в (1). По идее они оба его используют (и оба вызывают одинаковое количество copy/move конструкторов).

Comment: Тоже не очень понял, почему *"первые два варианта неверно используют move семантику"*. Понятно, что это хуже, чем две перегрузки (`const string &` + `string &&`), но по-моему это все равно нормальный вариант.

Comment: я не говорю, что это ужасный вариант. Если человек решил заморочитися именно на производительности - тогда сам по себе он неверный - лучше использовать комбинацию. Если же просто хочется написать по простому - тогда либо все по значению (но тут очень осторожным быть нужно, даже Майерс осторожничает), либо константная ссылка, которая работает предсказуемо.

Comment: @KoVadim Теперь вроде понял. Идея в том, что он и максимальную производительность не дает (как две перегрузки), и код усложняет? А я наоборот, обычно как раз поэтому его использую (как компромисс).

Answer (score 1):

"*Практика - критерий истины*" (с)

Проводим эксперимент для 5 вариантов.

На моей машине время вставки миллиона строк разными способами

```
 117.0 +- 3.9 ms     strings.push_back(std::move(str));
 118.3 +- 6.6 ms     strings.emplace_back(std::move(str));
 113.9 +- 4.4 ms     strings.push_back(str);
 114.5 +- 5.6 ms     strings.emplace_back(str);
 129.4 +- 9.9 ms     strings.emplace_back(str.data());
```

Вот [код](https://gitlab.com/disputant/rustackoverflow/-/blob/master/exper/strcopy.cpp).

Так что не занимайтесь преждевременной оптимизацией...

Да, если зарезервировать память для вектора - то вот:

```
 75.9 +- 3.4 ms
 73.6 +- 0.6 ms
 73.1 +- 0.7 ms
 72.2 +- 0.8 ms
 85.3 +- 0.8 ms
```

Как видите, принципиальной разницы нет...

Comment: У меня не скомпилировалось в https://godbolt.org/

Comment: @ueber Ничем не могу помочь, пользую VC++ 2017...

Comment: Можете тогда ещё вариант KoVadim с data() + размер померять?

Comment: Сделайте, пожалуйста, и мой вариант - ресайз и запись по итератору.

Comment: Ну как так "разницы нет", когда последний пример в обоих тестах выдает трудягу Шлемиэля с головой :)

Comment: а ещё не все знают, но для маленьких строк (из за SSO) move может быть "тяжелее":)

Comment: Люди, ну мам же дописать - раз плюнуть, мне сейчас просто некогда...  Просто copy-paste и вперед.

Comment: @KoVadim Автор вопроса ничего не говорил, о *каких именно* строках идет речь. В любом случае, думаю, не то он оптимизирует...

Comment: Ау, я ничего не оптимизирую! Мне надо знать, как лучше с точки зрения современных практик это делать! Мне всё равно, что там на миллисекунду будет дольше или нет :)

Comment: о, так нужно "современные методики":) Вот это именно я и уточнил в своем ответе в самом конце

Answer (score 0):

**upd:**

Нашёл [ответ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28144314), который ожидал услышать. Критика приветствуется.

Использовать `const std::string&` в параметре только тогда, когда не нужна никакая копия строки + используется API, которое работает только с заканчивающимися на `\0` строками, куда эту ссылку надо передавать. В остальных случаях, когда нужна копия, использовать передачу по значению + `std::move`, а когда не нужна - `std::string_view`.

Что касается разницы в `push_back` и `emplace_back`, то принципиальной разницы между 1 и 2 нет, но для читаемости лучше `push_back` имхо. Что касается последнего `emplace_back`, то там стоит также передавать размер, если не из-за скорости, то хотя бы потому, чтобы не было проблем для не заканчивающихся на `\0` `std::string_view`.

---

Решил проверить вызовы конструкторов:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

struct A {
    A() = default;
    
    A(const A&) {
        std::cout << "Copy\n";
    }

    A(A&&) noexcept {
        std::cout << "Move\n";
    }
};

struct B {
    B() {
        v.reserve(4);
    }

    void add_1(A a) {
        v.push_back(std::move(a));
    }

    void add_2(A a) {
        v.emplace_back(std::move(a));
    }

    void add_3(const A& a) {
        v.push_back(a);
    }

    void add_4(const A& a) {
        v.emplace_back(a);
    }

    std::vector<A> v;
};

int main() {
    B b{};
    A a{};

    b.add_1(a);
    std::cout << '\n';
    b.add_2(a);
    std::cout << '\n';
    b.add_3(a);
    std::cout << '\n';
    b.add_4(a);
    std::cout << '\n';
}
```

Результат:

> Copy Move
>
> Copy Move
>
> Copy
>
> Copy

Comment: Ваш тест неверен. Вы забываете о том, что когда вектору нужно увеличить размеры, то копирует/перемещает элементы в новое место. Поэтому, в третьем случае у Вас два лишних move. Но уже исправились

Comment: В любом случае, есть такое правило as-if и компилятор может выбросить некоторые конструкторы (потому что на них это правило не распространяется)

Comment: @KoVadim всё, теперь ок вроде

Comment: @KoVadim не может, потому что тогда не будет напечатано сообщение

Comment: для конструкторов имеет право нарушить и выбросить. Особенно это красиво работает, если возвращать с функции большой объект по значению (раньше оно называлось RVO, потом [temporary materialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion#Temporary_materialization))

Comment: @KoVadim где в этом коде он может что-то выбросить? Тут не возвращается ничего

Comment: прям в этом? да легко. Теоретически компилятор может доказать, что функция ничего полезного, кроме передачи дальше не делает и заинлайнить ее. Ну и добавить строку в вывод, что бы программист не пугался

Comment: @KoVadim так инлайн считается вызовом с точки зрения языка, инлайн это оптимизация, он нигде в стандарте не оговорен. Оговорено наблюдаемое поведение, а раз наблюдаемое поведение есть, то и вызов считается что был. В итоговом ассемблерном листинге это может быть просто 4 вызова << даже без какого-либо представления о структуре, но с точки зрения языка все конструкторы были вызваны

Comment: ещё раз - для конструкторов компилятор может нарушать это правило. Вы оперируете такими интересными конструкциями, при этом делаете простые ошибки. - https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/as_if "Copy elision is an exception from the as-if rule: the compiler may remove calls to move- and copy-constructors and the matching calls to the destructors of temporary objects even if those calls have observable side effects."

Comment: @KoVadim ну так тут copy elision нет. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision какой из указанных пунктов в этом коде?

Comment: прям здесь нет. Я же упомянул о возврате значения.

Comment: @KoVadim "прям в этом? да легко. Теоретически компилятор может доказать, что функция ничего полезного, кроме передачи дальше не делает и заинлайнить ее."

Comment: а это тоже может быть. Но я там добавил, что он вставит вызовы для печати строк.

Comment: @KoVadim ну а я на это ответил, что это будет считаться вызововом, потому что есть наблюдаемое поведение, на что вы привели, что есть исключение - copy elision, но здесь нет copy elision

Answer (score -2):

В некоторых случаях, ни один из представленных.

Мой недавний анализ ассемблера, который выдает `gcc 7.5.0 (SUSE Linux)` , показал, что быстрее всего что-то записывать в массив так:

```
a.resize(n); //будем вставлять n штук элементов
auto ins = a.begin();
for(...)
{
   *ins++= // new element
}
```

Объяснение такое - даже если перед тем, как много раз делать `push_back`, сделать `reserve` на новый размер, `GCC` будет проверять, что массив не пора расширять на *каждой вставке*, что неприятно - это и лишнее ветвление, и разрастание тела процедуры, с риском выскочить из кэша.

Если же работать с итератором, никаких проверок делаться не будет.

Если массив числовой, есть дополнительный бонус - цикл может будет раскручен, а операции вставки - векторизованы, то есть, за одну инструкцию можно вставлять не 1 число, а сразу пачку.

Comment: Так мне надо 1 строку добавить, а не n

Comment: Тогда очень вероятно, что вы занимаетесь преждевременной оптимизацией.

Answer (score -2):

В первом случае строка копируется два раза. Сначала в аргумент функции и второй раз в методе push_back. std::move здесь ни к чему. push_back в любом случае создает копию того, что в него прилетает.

```
void add_string(std::string str) {
    strings.push_back(std::move(str));
}
```

Второй случай бессмысленный. В emplace_back нужно передавать параметры конструктора. В данном случае он ни чем не отличается от push_back. std::move не нужен.

```
void add_string(std::string str) {
    strings.emplace_back(std::move(str));
}
```

Третий вариант рабочий. Создается только одна копия в push_back.

```
void add_string(const std::string& str) {
    strings.push_back(str);
}
```

Четвертый вариант неплох. Здесь правильное использование emplace_back. Строка сразу создается внутри вектора.

```
void add_string(std::string_view str) {
    strings.emplace_back(str.data());
}
```

Comment: Четвертый вариант ой как плох, потому что в нем сидит Шлемиэль http://rsdn.org/forum/humour/6110712.flat

Comment: Почему в 1 варианте 2 копирования, а не копирование и перемещение? Почему во втором не нужен `std::move`? Тогда же будет 2 копирования как раз.

Comment: @gbg А в каких случаях это будет работать как Шлемиэль?

Comment: Прежде чем копировать, нужно выделить память, а чтобы выделить память нужно отправить Шлемиэля искать у строки ноль.

Comment: @ueber надо понимать как работает std::move. он ничего никуда не перемещает а просто меняет тип на rvalue.

Comment: @libhet ну да, так почему он во втором не нужен? Есть конструктор для &&, есть копирующий. Без std::move будет вызван копирующий в моём понимании

Comment: @ueber emplace_back это шаблонный метод, который принимает переменное число аргументов по r-value ссылке.

Comment: @libhet да, но с std::move - rvalue+rvalue=rvalue, без - lvalue+rvalue=lvalue

Comment: @ueber да, но это в любом случае будет ссылка. Либо r-value ссылка, если сделать move, либо l-value ссылка если ничего не делать.

Comment: @libhet проверил вызовы конструкторов, смотреть мой ответ

Comment: @ueber ок, признаю, был не прав